# Google Maps Engine API No scroll (read the other threads)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

According to some other threads the api version 3 should disable scroll zoom with scrollwheel: false, I have

```
   var opts = $.extend({scrollwheel: false}, $.fn.gMap.defaults, options);
```

in $.fn.gMap.defaults scrollwheel is also false and also I have commented out  this

```
   var map_options = { /*scrollwheel: opts.scrollwheel,*/ scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: opts.doubleclickzoom };
```

It is still zooming. The only thing I can do is to disable all mouse interactions on that iframe but then nobody can toggle the navigation
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your map position and zoom, you can disabled the scroll wheel underneath, like so -

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.755653101471765, 91.08712517812499),
  zoom: 2,
  scrollwheel: false,
});
```

I hope that's what you needed.